# Entity framework many to many keeps adding extra record

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to add a new record to the link table using entityframework code first. What I have is a many to many on `User` and `Role`. The scenario I have is that when I'm changing a role for the user, I delete all their previous roles and add the new roles as follows:

```
//Delete all associated roles for user
var roleUser = db.Users.Include(r => r.Roles).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == user.UserId);
var usersRoles = roleUser.Roles;

usersRoles.ForEach(role => roleUser.Roles.Remove(role));

//add the new roles
roleUser.Roles.AddRange(detachedUser.Roles);

db.SaveChanges();
```

So it removes them perfectly. But when adding new roles, it doesn't only add it to the link table but also the `Role` table. A completely new role gets added without a `RoleName`. `user.Roles` would contain an item with the following data:

```
RoleId;//1 <-- this Id exists in the database already but yet still it creates one instead of a linktable record.
RoleName;//null
```

How do I prevent EF from adding a whole new record and just add a record to the link table?

**Update:** I ended up doing this:

```
var roleUser = db.Users.Include(r => r.Roles).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == user.UserId);
var roles = db.Roles;

foreach (var role in roles)
{
     if (user.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == role.RoleId))
     {
          roleUser.Roles.Add(role);
     }
     else
     {
         roleUser.Roles.Remove(role);
     }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Apparently it is solved but cant get an understanding of what has solved it. Could you please post again the part of the answer that prevents creating a new role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to save before adding new roles to the user

```
//Delete all associated roles for user 
var roleUser = db.Users.Include(r => r.Roles).FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == user.UserId); 
var usersRoles = roleUser.Roles; 

usersRoles.ForEach(role => roleUser.Roles.Remove(role));  
db.SaveChanges(); 

roleUser.Roles.AddRange(user.Roles); //add the new roles 
db.SaveChanges();
```

Edit:

Have a look at this :

```
roleUser.Roles.AddRange(user.Roles); //add the new roles
```

where do `user.Roles` come from ?

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem after adding the second SaveChanges.

Comment: I think its the way I'm adding the new roles. I probably have to get all of them from the database and add them

Comment: when you have problems like this, you may also want to look at your binding configuration. I've had problemes like these in the past.

Comment: did getting them back from the database change anything ?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how I can a range of items from the database

Comment: @Alexandre see the question I edited. `user.Roles` is coming back from the view with only the `RoleId`

Comment: @lol coder, you've found the reason for the creation of the roles. the entities were seen as new. happy to see you've solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you have is that you need to attach your Roles before adding them to the user.

you also don't need to remove them all, simply remove those removed and then only add the new ones.

Comment: I agree with @moi_meme onthe part where you only need to remove the ones that need to be removed. On the other hand, I don't think this is an issue that touched the attached/detached states. since the objects are never detached.

Comment: @Alexandre Brisebois - I Wrote that because of his variable is called DetachedUser

Comment: my bad I hadn't noticed that part

Answer (score 0):

For each roll that you add you could try checking or setting the entity state.  For example here I set the set to unchaged.  This way it wont attempt to insert or update it.

```
myContext.Entry(roll).State = EntityState.Unchanged
```

More info here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx

Comment: true, but if he saved before trying to add new roles, woudln't the state of the entities be unchanged (after the save)